# Are there games with board presentation similar to Talisman and Relic?

Tags: game-design

I'm referring to the way the art for different spaces spills over into other areas of the board, creating a panorama or telling a story with the outer and inner regions of the board. Are there any games with similar presentation?

Answer (score 2):

In that graphical sense a really wonderful game that strikes me as similar is Yggdrasil.  It is Norse mythology based, cooperative, a good challenge, and pretty enough to be a poster.

[image: Game shot]

Comment: That picture is a game in progress.

Answer (score 0):

There is also Tannhauser from Fantasy Flight Games. See [boardgamegeek](http://www.boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/25261/tannhauser) for some pics of the boards.